# RequestJS - SSL connection is authorized but getPeerCertificate() returns null

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, requestjs

I'm using the node package [RequestJS](https://github.com/request/request) v2.65.0 on node v4.1.2

I'm trying to [read the SSL certificate](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed) from certain sites (eg. GitHub.com). **This previously worked on node 0.12**. On node 4.2.1, however, `getPeerCertificate()` returns `null`.

For example:

```
request({
  url: 'https://github.com'
}, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log('err:', err)
  console.log('peerCertificate:',res.req.connection.getPeerCertificate());
  console.log('authorized:',res.req.connection.authorized);
  console.log('authorizationError:',res.req.connection.authorizationError);
});
```

will print out

```
err: null
peerCertificate: null
authorized: true
authorizationError: null
```

i.e. the secure connection is established but the certificate is null.

From my (basic) understanding, if the connection is authorized, there should be a peer certificate.

I've tried with a number of SSL sites, and the result is the same. Is there an option in request, a bug with Node 4, or a misunderstanding on my part about how [SSL/TLS works in node](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed)?

Comment: I don't see why it should work at all. You got an error: what makes you think there is even a TCP connection? let alone an authenticated SSL connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is because the `getPeerCertificate()` will only output anything when the connection is in `connected` state, but when you receive your response, it's likely already too late.

If you want `getPeerCertificate` to output, you should do it at the TLS level independently as such:

```
const socket = require('tls').connect(443, "github.com", () => {
  console.log('client connected',
    socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
```

**Important! : Do not put the protocol in the URL. Rather, use require('url').parse(yourURL).hostname as the target.**

More info and example here: https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback

Answer (score 4):

@nembleton is correct about why this happens. There's an issue for this at https://github.com/request/request/issues/1867

Rather than dropping down to raw TLS sockets, you can stick with Request and use its stream API. This approach is particularly useful if you're taking advantage of other Request features that would make the low-level connection more complicated (e.g. going through an HTTPS proxy).

The code snippet in the original question becomes:

```
request({
  url: 'https://github.com'
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('err:', err);
})
.on('response', function (res) {
  console.log('peerCertificate:',res.socket.getPeerCertificate());
  console.log('authorized:',res.socket.authorized);
  console.log('authorizationError:',res.socket.authorizationError);
});
```

(I used `res.socket` rather than `res.req.connection` for brevity/directness, but either will work.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this question when building an api to check SSL certificates expiry.

Here is the code works for me.

```js
import https from 'node:https';

const checkSsl = (hostname) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const req = https.request({
    hostname,
    agent: new https.Agent({ maxCachedSessions: 0 }), // Disable session caching
  }, (res) => {
    const certificate = res.socket.getPeerCertificate();
    resolve(certificate);
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    reject(e);
  });
  req.end();
});
```

`getPeerCertificate()` would return `null` when the session is established and cached. But a non-cached agent would guarantee detailed result.